# Concurrency considerations for two level par_iter

Tags: parallel-processing, rust

I'm trying to use ndarray_parallel in Rust would like to check if there's any considerations I need to be careful with. Specifically the code looks something like this,

```
let mut mat = Array2::<f64>::zeros((1000, 1000);
Zip::from(mat.axis_iter(Axis(0))).par_apply(|row| {

    row.into_par_iter().map(...).collect() ;
});
```

Do i need to be careful with what i do inside of map()?

Comment: It is best that you provide a concrete example of what you tried but fear that there is a problem, and exactly which problem you refer to. The given code does not compile. Note also that the Rust compiler will already protect you from data races.

Comment: after reading up more on compiler guarantees in the Rust approach i realised my concerns are invalid :)